# How to parse and extract some html values from an html page which might not be valid?

Tags: python, html, parsing, web-scraping

I need to parse an html page which might not be valid. Actually, many of them because I get them from the Internet.  In particular, I need to get values of some tags. I can do that via regular expressions, but I guess they're not a good fit for this task, especially because the html page is quite big.

My question is, what library should I choose for parsing such a page and getting the values of the tags/attributes I need?

Answer (score 1):

Try bs4
You can parse a html document by

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(open("*.html","r").read(),"html.parser")
soup.title  #return the node of title
print str(soup.title.string)  #return the text in title
alist = soup.findAll('a')  #return a list of all nodes of tag <a>
alist[0]['href']  #return the href attribute of this node as a str
blist = soup.findAll('div',{'class':'container'})  #return a list of all nodes of tag <div> whose class is container
```

More information can be found about it on https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: so what if an html page isn't valid?

Comment: What does your 'invalid' mean? Could you give me some examples?

Comment: If you want to run a crawler, it will get most information you want even if there are some mistakes in the html page. And in fact you can use

Comment: max, ti pohodu tupoi.

Comment: @Kumakaja Use another parser than `'html.parser'` then.  Either `lxml.html` or `html5lib`. Both can parse invalid HTML. The former is faster, the latter written in pure Python and interpretes (broken) HTML like most browsers do these days.  See the documentation of BeautifulSoup for information about those parsers and how to install them.

Answer (score -1):

if you really are bothered with invalid html, you might apply a `pre-processing` to the extracted html to make it close to valid xml. See how:

```
import requests
import re
res = requests.get('http://page.com');

# remove everything before the `body` tag
res.text = re.sub(r"(.*?)<body>",'<body>', res.text ) 

# remove unneeded, long white spaces
res.text = re.sub(r"\s+",' ', res.text ) 

# make unclosed `p` tags closed 
res.text = re.sub(r"<p>",'</p><p>', res.text )

# etc.

# here you start to parse your brushed-up code
```